# Htaccess rewrite to rename the first folder, remove the second, and substitute the file name's underscores with hyphens

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

There are a number of external sites pointing back to our site looking for the following url:

```
domain.com/bananas/ripe/name_of_file
```

I'd like to add a rule to the htaccess file that would redirect requests of this type (looking for the same `name_of_file`) to:

```
domain.com/apples/name-of-file #notice the hyphens
```

I've tried a few variations of

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /bananas/ripe/
RewriteRule ^bananas/ripe/(.*)$ /apples/$1 [L,R=301]
```

But it's not happening because I don't know how to go about replacing the underscores of the `name_of_file` to hyphens of `name-of-file`.

Full htaccess:

```
<Files .htaccess>
 order allow,deny
 deny from all
</Files>

# Don't show any directory without an index file
Options -Indexes

# Dont list files in index pages
IndexIgnore *

# Don't need to tell everyone we're apache
ServerSignature Off

<FilesMatch "\.(ttf|otf|eot|woff|font.css)$">
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</FilesMatch>

AddType application/x-shockwave-flash   .swf
AddType video/mpeg          .mpeg .mpg .mpe
AddType video/quicktime         .qt .mov .m4v .flac
AddType video/x-msvideo         .avi
AddType video/x-sgi-movie       .movie 
AddType video/ogg           .ogg .ogv
AddType video/mp4           .mp4
AddType video/webm          .webm
AddType audio/x-aiff            .aif .aiff .aifc
AddType audio/x-wav             .wav
AddType audio/x-pn-realaudio        .ram
AddType image/svg+xml           .svg .svgz
AddEncoding gzip            .svgz
AddType application/vnd.ms-fontobject  .eot
AddType font/truetype                  .ttf
AddType font/opentype                  .otf
AddType font/woff                      .woff
AddType image/gif           .gif .GIF
AddType image/jpeg          .jpeg .jpg .jpe .JPG 
AddType image/vnd.microsoft.icon        .ico
AddType text/x-component                .htc
AddType text/xml            .xml
AddType text/x-component        .htc
AddDefaultCharset utf-8

AddCharset utf-8 .html .css .js .xml .json .rss

ErrorDocument 403 http://domain.com
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php?/home/error

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(ACT=.*)$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(URL=.*)$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(CSS=.*)$ [NC]   
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php\?&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]

RewriteCond $1 !\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^bananas/ripe/(.*)$ /apples/$1 [L,NC,R]

# if there is only one underscore then repalce it by - and redirect
RewriteRule ^(apples)/([^_]*)_([^_]*)$ /$1/$2-$3 [L,R=302]

# if there are more than one underscores then "repeatedly" repalce it by -
# and set env var
RewriteRule ^(apples)/([^_]*)_([^_]*)_(.*) $1/$2-$3-$4 [E=USCOR:1]

# if USCORE env var is set and there is no underscore left then redirect
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_USCOR} =1
RewriteRule ^(apples)/([^_]+)$ /$1/$2 [L,R=302]

<FilesMatch "\.(html|htm|php)$">
  Header set imagetoolbar "no"
</FilesMatch>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER}     !^$
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.(gif|jpe?g?|png|mov|svg|mp4)$           [NC]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER}     !^https?://([^.]+\.)?domain\. [NC]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER}     domain:8888\. [NC]
 RewriteRule \.(gif|jpe?g?|png)$                             - [F,NC,L]
</ifModule>
```

Comment: Try `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/bananas/ripe/ [NC]` instead

Comment: It could have worked. But I've just noticed that my initial request is a little more complicated than I first described. Will update it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use these rules:

```
RewriteRule ^bananas/ripe/(.*)$ /apples/$1 [L,NC,R=302]

# if there is one underscore left then redirect
RewriteRule ^(apples)/([^_]*)_([^_]*)/?$ /$1/$2-$3 [NC,L,R=302]

# if there are more than one underscores then "repeatedly" repalce it by -
RewriteRule ^(apples)/([^_]*)_(.*)$ $1/$2-$3 [NC,L]
```

Comment: Very clever.  I've implemented it but it's not working. I've tested the first rule alone by pointing the browser to `domain.com/bananas/ripe/` and I get a 404 screen. And I tried also the `domain.com/apples/name_of_file` to see if the second part of your rule set could at least manage the underscore to hyphen substitution, but it too failed.

Comment: Thanks again for your time on this. We're getting closer but not quite there. I've tested the `domain/bananas/ripe` and it now redirects to `domain.com/apples`. So that works. However, the underscore to hyphen rule is not generating the desired result and I get a 404 page.

Comment: There's no htaccess in the `/apples/` folder. The url I tried was `domain.com/bananas/ripe/file_name_or_other` and then I tried `domain.com/apples/file_name_or_other` to see if it could deal with the uscore to hyphen substitution.

Comment: Nearly there!! It works only when there's no underscore and with one underscore in the `file_name`. If there's more than one underscore I get a 404.

Comment: Nope. Same results as previous version.

Comment: Yes, it works with one underscore. But it doesn't with multiple ones.